# Scheduled job fails when run via trigger, but works when run manually

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled job to run the following command:

`copy 'C:\Users\tdjeilati\Desktop\RDP.rdg' '\\fil03\Dept_1Z\Public\my'`

This copies a file to a remote server.
I have a job trigger `-AtLogon`.

When I log in to my PC, it runs the job.
When I retrieve that job with receive-job, I get the job got an an access is denied error:

[image]

But then I run the job by hand, and it works correctly! What gives?

[image]

I don't understand why it fails when running from the job trigger but works when I run it manually in powershell. I can only assume that the environment/permissions are different.

EDIT: One thing I noticed is that the job that runs from the jobtrigger doesn't have any childJobs, but the job that I start from command line has child jobs. Why should there be a difference?

Answer (score 0):

The scheduled task may not be running under your user account.  This could explain why it works when you manually start the job.

Verify that the task is running as a user with rights to the file and the remote share.

Comment: In the script of the job, I output the username and domain. I see that with the scheduled job it is running under the exact same user account and domain, yet it fails. What else could be different between the scheduledjob that runs via trigger and the one that I run by commandline?